# Configuring a biztalk sendport to an EBS package

Tags: oracle, configuration, biztalk, biztalk-2010, send-port

Okay, I've been looking over this for the past couple of days but I cannot get it to consume a message. Here is my basic message schema structure. The message is created against this schema through a pipeline (works, tested).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/XXSCHEMA/Package/XXPAC_AQ_PKG" 
           xmlns="http://XXCOMPANY.Schemas.adEnqueueRequest" 
           xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ENQUEUE">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="p_queue_name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
        <xs:element name="p_payload" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
        <xs:element name="p_message_type" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The send port is configured like to use the WCF-OracleEBSAdapter and I've confirmed I have all my environment details set up correctly(ie, username, password, TNS information.)

The current bts action I've set is:

```
<BtsActionMapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Operation Name="ENQUEUE" Action="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/XXSCHEMA/Package/XXPAC_AQ_PKG/ENQUEUE" />
</BtsActionMapping>
```

But I've tried all of the action mappings on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788171.aspx to get it working. Each time my message suspends and the event log shows:

A message sent to adapter "WCF-OracleEBSAdapter" on send port "SENDPORTNAME" with URI "SENDPORTURI" is suspended.

```
 Error details: Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.UnsupportedOperationException: Action "http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/XXSCHEMA/Package/XXPAC_AQ_PKG/ENQUEUE" is invalid.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result) 
 MessageId:  {26BF83FF-742E-4649-8FCC-45729767FF8E}
 InstanceID: {CA97B656-FC1A-4884-8A6A-F95D156298ED}
```

The aim of this send port is to call a routine on an oracle server that will place a message on a specified queue. Has anyone successfully done this before? Can anyone see anything that might be wrong with my configuration. Any tips would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operation isn't formed correctly.  You seem to have an two parts (XXPAC_AQ_PKG/ENQUEUE) after Package instead of one.

The correct format as per [Message Schemas for Functions and Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185204%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) and the URL you quoted

`http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/[SCHEMA]/Package/[PACKAGE_NAME]`

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure that bit out. The schema itself was a little wrong and the namespace I should have been using was "http://schemas.microsoft.com/OracleEBS/2008/05/PackageApis/[SCHEMA]/[PACKAGE]"
With an action of PackageApis/[SCHEMA]/[PACKAGE]/[OPERATION]